# Denseness of a sequence in 2-Torus

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems

I want to show that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are rationally independent irrational numbers i.e. $\forall m,n \in\mathbb{Z}$ , $m\alpha + n\beta \not\in\mathbb{Z}$ , then the sequence

$\{ (n\alpha$ (mod 1) , $n\beta$ (mod 1) $\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in 2-Torus.

I managed to argue that $\{n\alpha$ (mod 1) $\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\{n\beta$ (mod 1) $\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ are dense in 1-Torus. However, I do not see how to use rational independence to arrive at denseness of the above sequence in two torus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\{(k\alpha,k\beta) \mod 1: k \in \mathbb Z\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb T^2$, and its closure is a closed subgroup.  If that is not all of $\mathbb T^2$, there must be a nontrivial member of the dual group $\mathbb Z^2$ that annihilates it, i.e. a pair of integers $(m,n)$, not both $0$, such that $m\alpha + n\beta \in \mathbb Z$, which would say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are rationally dependent.

Comment: I am sorry but what are you using to say that any non-trivial closed subgroup must be annihilated by some member of the dual group? Perhaps I do not have enough background to understand.

Comment: Let $H$ be a nontrivial closed subgroup of locally compact abelian group $G$. Then the quotient group $G/H$ is a nontrivial locally compact abelian group. 
It must have a nontrivial character $\phi: G/H \to \mathbb T$.  If $\pi: G \to G/H$ is the quotient map, then $\phi \circ \pi: G \to \mathbb T$ is a nontrivial character of $G$ that annihilates $H$.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I am very grateful.